Optional Stopping Theorem for expected number of flips
What is the expected number of flips of a fair coin needed to have $10$ more heads flipped than tails or $8$ more tails flipped than heads ?
I wanted to do this formally with the following reasoning, but noticed a couple of issues:
Let $H_k$ (sum of $X_k$ Ber($1/2$) random variables) be the number of heads after $k$ flips. $T_k=k-H_k$ is the number of tails after $k$ flips.
We define the stopping time $$T:=\min \{k \in \Bbb N | H_k - T_k = 10 \cup  T_k - H_k = 8\}= \min \{k \in \Bbb N | 2H_k = 10+k \cup  2H_k = k-8\}$$
where the last equality comes from replacing $T_k$ with its definition.
Now the first problem I see is that since $k-8<10+k$, $H_k$ increasing with the flips will always hit $k-8$ first. If $k=20$ for example, we want $T$ to be the first time we have 15 heads or 6 heads so it necessarily reaches the second condition first. This is of course not the case but why? I checked the stopping time over and over...
Then I wanted to do something I always want to apply but very rarely get nice results: use the fact that $H_k - k/2$ is a martingale and use optional stopping theorem which leads me to $2E(H_T)=E(T) $ and I never know what to do with this equation in such problems. I try to consider $H_t^2$ and its variance to get a second equation but it doesn't lead anywhere.
Please note that I already have an alternative solution to the problem and would like to know how can I fix my attempt.
